# Tomcat text file encoding

Tags: java, tomcat, character-encoding, java-io

I have a java webapp which reads from file on disk and returns the needed values. The file on disk contains UTF-8 characters.

Example of the file content:

```
lähedus teeb korterist atraktiivse üüriobjekti välismaalastele
```

When the webapp is run on `localhost*` then the servlet reads from disk and returns:

```
lähedus teeb korterist atraktiivse üüriobjekti välismaalastele
```

When I run the same app on a separate server the same request returns this:

```
l??hedus teeb korterist atraktiivse ????riobjekti v??lismaalastele
```

This is purely an encoding issue but I don't know how to solve it.

What I have tried:

- I added this to config/server.xml

  ```
  <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" 
  URIEncoding="UTF-8"/> <!-- THIS PART
  ```

But it didn't help.
What should I change in config to have it working on server as well?
Thanks!

EDIT

I am reading from a txt file on server containing json strings.
I am using java BufferReader to read the content. As I mentioned in the comments, this problem is not caused by the reader because the same works on localhost.

I am sending the response via a servlet which just flushes the json string out. Again the same story as with the reader.

I get the question marks on any client I make the request (browser, android, etc).

Comment: What does URI encoding have to do with the *content* of the files? I'm afraid you're not being very clear at the moment.

Comment: The content of the file does not matter. I just wanted to clear that the original data doesn't have the questionmarks

Comment: So why did you say "The file on disk contains UTF-8 characters"? It's still really unclear to me what the problem is. What do you mean by "it gives me question marks"? Please put more effort into being really, really clear in your question.

Comment: I edited my question to be more precise. Thanks

Comment: Given that that's the *content* of the file, it's still not clear why you think that *URI* encoding is relevant. The content isn't returned in the URI, is it? It's also not clear how you're reading the data and serving it, or how you're downloading it, or how you're then viewing it.

Comment: I figured those don't matter since it is all wokring on localhost but not on the separate server. But I will add these point in the edit.

Comment: There's still no actual code, making it really hard to help you. Yes, you're using `BufferedReader` - but how are you creating that? What are you doing with it? This may well be a matter of you using the default encoding in your code, and that changing based on which server you're using.

Comment: If you don't know the encoding you should use input and output streams, not readers and writers. There is no reason to treat this file any differently from any other opaque file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local file seems to be in UTF-8, with a wrong conversion to some single-byte encoding. As one sees a multi-byte sequence for one special char resulting in two unconvertible chars (`?`).

The application is reading it without specification of the encoding, hence using the system's encoding. That is not something you want.

And then you need to find the wrong reading code: often there is an overloaded method where one can add the encoding. Notorious however is FileReader, that utility class always uses the default encoding. Check occurrences of:

- InputStreamReader
- new String
- String.getBytes
- Scanner

For good order, but probably not the case here: any response yielding that text should specify the charset in the content-type.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to debug using Your directions. Yeah the system encoding may be different on my maching and the server and thus it sure can be the readers fault :P